# Nativescript http data not loading in view

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to follow this tutorial for Nativescript: http://www.beer-tutorials.org/2015/12/01/NativeScript-Beers/

Here is my code:

## main-page.ts

```
var http = require("http");
var observableArray = require("data/observable-array");
var beerList = new observableArray.ObservableArray([]);
var observableModule = require("data/observable");
var pageData = new observableModule.Observable();

exports.beers = function() {
    http.getJSON("http://www.beer-tutorials.org/beers/beers.json").then(function(r) {
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
        for (var i = 0; i< r.length; i++) {
            var beer = { name: r[i].name, description: r[i].description, alcohol: r[i].alcohol } 
            beerList.push(beer);
        }
        // console.log(beerList)
    }, function(e) {

        console.log(e);

    });
  };

  function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    pageData.set("beerList", beerList);
    // it links an xml "beerList" variable to a js beerList variable
    page.bindingContext = pageData;
}
```

## main-page.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo" class="page">
    <!--
    The ActionBar is the NativeScript common abstraction over the Android ActionBar and iOS NavigationBar.
    http://docs.nativescript.org/ui/action-bar
    -->
    <Page.actionBar>
        <ActionBar title="My App" icon="" class="action-bar">
        </ActionBar>
    </Page.actionBar>
    <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
        <Button text="Get beer list" height="50px" tap="beers" style="width:300px;border:none;font-size:20px;" />
            <ListView items="{{ beerList }}" >
            <ListView.itemTemplate>
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
                <Label id="name" text="{{name}}" class="beerName" />
                <Label id="description" text="{{ description }}" textWrap="true" />
            </StackLayout>
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
            </ListView>
    </StackLayout> 
</Page>
```

When I click the "Get beer list" button I don't get anything on the screen. I can console.log in main-page.ts and see the json data coming through, so I know that is good. I suspect the data is not getting from main-page.ts to main-page.xml. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `pageLoaded` method callback is neither exported nor called from XML. Instead you have a `navigatingTo` listener in your XML which seems never defined in your JS. You just got to fix either of those.

Answer (score 0):

Here was the code for the fix in case it helps someone else out. Note the addition of the `export` keyword for the pageLoaded function in main-page.tx, and also the addition of `loaded="onPageLoaded"` in main-page.xml. More info here: https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/page

## main-page.ts

```
var http = require("http");
var observableArray = require("data/observable-array");
var beerList = new observableArray.ObservableArray([]);
var observableModule = require("data/observable");
var pageData = new observableModule.Observable();

exports.beers = function() {
    http.getJSON("http://www.beer-tutorials.org/beers/beers.json").then(function(r) {
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
        for (var i = 0; i< r.length; i++) {
            var beer = { name: r[i].name, description: r[i].description, alcohol: r[i].alcohol } 
            beerList.push(beer);
        }
        // console.log(beerList)
    }, function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
  };

  export function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    pageData.set("beerList", beerList);
    // it links an xml "beerList" variable to a js beerList variable
    page.bindingContext = pageData;
}
```

## main-page.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="onPageLoaded" class="page">
    <!--
    The ActionBar is the NativeScript common abstraction over the Android ActionBar and iOS NavigationBar.
    http://docs.nativescript.org/ui/action-bar
    -->
    <Page.actionBar>
        <ActionBar title="My App" icon="" class="action-bar">
        </ActionBar>
    </Page.actionBar>
    <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
        <Button text="Get beer list" height="50px" tap="beers" style="width:300px;border:none;font-size:20px;" />
            <ListView items="{{ beerList }}" >
            <ListView.itemTemplate>
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
                <Label id="name" text="{{name}}" class="beerName" />
                <Label id="description" text="{{ description }}" textWrap="true" />
            </StackLayout>
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
            </ListView>
    </StackLayout> 
</Page>
```